# Is there a simple way to add a zero in between a 4 digit number?

Tags: decimal-expansion

I want some formula which can take as an input a 4 digit number and outputs a 5 digit number. This 5 digit number is actually the input with a zero in between.
Example:
input: 1234 -> output: 12034
input: 6570 -> output: 65070
...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is

Comment: Your description couldn't be simpler. Perhaps you are asking for some other kind of description? If so, you should be more explicit about what kind of description you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $n \mapsto n+900(\lfloor\frac{n}{100}\rfloor)$ ?

Edited to add: I don't know whether this is the most computationally efficient formula.  Now that I'm thinking about it, the question of efficiency is quite interesting, but I don't have the expertise to know whether I could have done better.